# Get identity value of all rows inserted

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, identity

I can use `Scope_Identity()` to get the last identity value inserted into an identity column. But how can i get identity values of all rows which are inserted in a insert statement?

Example

```
insert into DestinationTbl select * from SourceTbl where [col1]='xyz'
```

Above statement may insert more than one rows into a table. So i want identity value of all the rows which are inserted. How it can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the output clause to throw the inserted rows into a table variable. Then you'll be able to see all of the identity values.

Link for the output clause:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx